# How to adding .00 at the end of the numbers within a text file using sed

Tags: linux, sed

So what I'm trying to do is take in a text file that has this:

```
stacy 450000
fred 23000
```

And then add a `$` in front of the numbers while also adding a `.00` at the end. What I have right now is

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{3,}?)([0-9][0-9])/$\1.\2/' filename
```

but the problem I'm having now is adding the .00 at the end and not placed right in the middle of the numbers.

Comment: Do you want `450000.00` or `4500.00`?

Comment: 450000.00 please

Comment: Perhaps this could help too `sed 's_ _ $_g' filename | sed 's_$_.00_g'`. Replaces space with a space followed by dollar. Adds  .00 at the end of the line.

Comment: With awk: `awk '$2="$" $2 ".00"' file`

Answer (score 1):

If you want `.00` added at the end, you don't need to capture different parts of the number in capture groups. Just match the entire number, and put a literal `.00` in the replacement.

In the replacement, `&` gets the entire match.

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]+/$&.00/' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^([^[:digit:]]*[[:space:]]*)([[:digit:]]*$)/\1\$\2.00/p' file
stacy $450000.00
fred $23000.00
```